# Obtaining Raw Data from NagiosXI and/or OPSview

Tags: nagios, opsview

I am currently working on completing my Masters Thesis project. In order to do so I need to be able to obtain the raw data accumulated in NagiosXI and/or OPSview. Because both of these are based off of the Nagios core, I assume the method to obtaining the raw data may be similar. This raw data is needed so that I can at a later time perform specific statical calculations which relate to my Masters Thesis. I have looked online and so far found some Nagios plugins which obtain raw data and then manipulate it for graphs and visuals, but I need the raw numbers in order to complete my calculations.

I am also researching to see if I can create maybe a PHP script, or some other language, that will extract the data from Nagios and save it in a word or excel document. However, this would be a bit of extra work as I am unfamiliar with either PHP or MySQL queries. Because of this I hope to be able to find a plugin, or something similar, that can get the data for me.

Answer (score 0):

Cyanide,

I can't speak for NagiosXI, but I can for Opsview :)

You could access the data that is stored in the RRD files. You can use rrdtool dump to pull the values out or use a URL like: /rrdfetch?start=1307608993&end=1307695393&hsm=opsview%3A%3ACheck%20Loadavg%3A%3Aload1&hsm=opsview%3A%3ACheck%20Loadavg%3A%3Aload5

And this returns back the JSON data points. This is undocumented, but is used to power the interactive javascript graphing.

Alternatively, if you have ODW enabled with full statistics, then the raw data is stored in the ODW database and you can then extract the raw data with SQL commands. See http://docs.opsview.com/doku.php?id=opsview-community:odw for more information.

Ton

Answer (score 0):

You can try use mk livestatus http://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_livestatus.html
or http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/APIs/JSON/Nagios2JSON/details
All this tools get you status data without need to go to DB or status file. While XI is based on Nagios it can still work with him.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at http://dmytro.github.com/nagira

It's a web services API to access Nagios data. You can get all hosts, service status data, objects configuration in multiple formats JSON, XML or YAML.